# Deep Linking In Nested Navigation in React Navigation 5

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-v6

How to implement deep linking in nested navigators in React Navigation. Here I have a nested stack navigator:

```js
function AuthStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen component={Login} name="Login" />  // deep link this screen
        <Stack.Screen component={ResetPassword} name="ResetPassword" />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

and it is nested within another main stack navigator:

```js
const linking = {
  prefixes: ["wagal://"],
  config: {
    screens: {
      AuthStack: "login",  // this doesn't reference `Login` screen on deep linking
    },
  },
};

function homeStack() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen component={AuthStack} name="AuthStack" />  // here
        // ...
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I tried to deep link "wagal://login/" to `Login` screen through:

```js
screens: {
  AuthStack: "login",
},
```

but it didn't work, I also tried:

```js
screens: {
  Login: "login",
},
```

they aren't working, I couldn't find anything in documentation either. How do I resolve this issue? thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### try to handle it as nested navigators.

`AuthStack` is parent name.
`Login` is route name.
`login` is url path.

```js
const config = {
  screens: {
    AuthStack: {
      screens: {
        Login: 'login',
      },
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you so much. I thought nested deep linking isn't supported.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to use it with bottom navigation bar and One stack?